# @Embedded object not saved when private

Tags: java, jpa, embeddable

Let's start with an entity with an embedded structure.

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity implements Serializable {

  @Embedded private MyEmbeddedObject myEmbeddedObject;

  ...
}

@Embeddable
public class MyEmbeddedObject implements Serializable {

  @Column(name = "first_col", precision = 38, scale = 18)
  private Double firstCol;

  ...
}
```

The content here is not important. These objects are created in a Java FX application. Once created or modified, they are stored in a database using JPA repositories.

I've observed the following behavior and would like to know if this is normal:

1. When an object `MyEntity` is created the very first time from my Java FX interface, JPA
   will store everything properly in the database, which is the expected behavior.
2. When I try to modify `firstCol` from the interface, this modification is
   displayed properly but its value will not be stored unless `MyEmbeddedObject`
   is a **protected** variable of `MyObject`. If `MyEmbeddedObject` is private, it becomes unmodifiable. Values can always be displayed but cannot be modified.

Anyone has any ideas why? This is not a blocking situation because I have a workaround. I'm curious if someone knows if this behavior is normal.

Comment: Once you modify `firstCol` value, do you save it again into database? Did you try: [saveandflush](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-save-saveandflush)

Comment: @Valijon To answer your question, of course I try to save it into database. As I mentioned, everything works well when a new object is created and saved into database with a private embedded object.